# Is it standard to use jQuery AJAX in Zend framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I want to call server when change  on combobox. Is the following jquery code is standard in Zend Framework

```
   $("select[name=month]").change(function(){
    var month = $("select[name=month]").val();
    if(month != 0){
        var data={
            "month":month,
            "year":$("select[name=year]").val()
        };
         jQuery.ajax({
          url: "/visits/visit/get-visits",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: data,
          success: getAllVisits,
          error:onError
});


    }
});
```

Is this way is accepted in the standard of Zend framework or not?

Comment: It's working, but is this way of coding accepted in the standard of Zend Framework! that's the question ...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this and try to compare:

- [ZendX_JQuery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.html)

  - [Introduction](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.introduction.html)
  - [ZendX_JQuery View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.view.html)
  - [ZendX_JQuery Form Elements and Decorators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.form.html)

*I have worked on some projects using Zend Framework but I did not used above helpers. For me, it does not really a matter. I will just put this jQuery code in a JavaScript file and place that file in `public/js` folder. Now you can include this file in Zend Views to make it workable. That's it.*

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. For links you provide, I read them, but I can't handle the jquery events without using the way I write in the question. It provides limited options for autocomplete for exmaple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think jQuery is supported out of the box. I have found importing the jQuery library while boostrapping to be the easiest approach.

I have put this line in a bootrap function where I initializw view settings:

```
$this->_view->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js');
```

Then I can write plain jQuery in my view files.